# Is there a way to check that a dictionary key is not defined in ansible task?

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook, conditional

So in my code I have a task:

```yaml
- name: cool task
  shell: 'touch iamnotcool.txt'
  when: me.cool is not defined
```

and my vars looks like:

```yaml
---
me:
  stumped: yes
```

So when I run the task it comes back with the following error:

```yaml
{"failed": true, "msg": "The conditional check 'me.cool' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (me.cool): 'dict object' has no attribute 'cool'."}
```

Answer (score 59):

The syntax you included:

```
when: me.cool is not defined
```

is correct.

You can also use `not in`:

```
when: "'cool' not in me"
```

---

The problem is that your error message:

> The conditional check 'me.cool' failed.

claims your condition is defined as:

```
when: me.cool
```

So, either there is some bug in the version you use (but you did not share which one it is) and there were [known issues](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/16013), or you did not post the exact task that caused the error.

Comment: The error could still happen, if he did not post the original code an ommited a second when-condition which refers to the same value.
This works:
`when: is_installed.rc is defined and is_installed.rc == 0`
This does not:
`when: is_installed.rc is defined` `\n` `when is_installed.rc == 0`

Comment: this form is useful for putting in front of the condition which failed (& which you still possibly want to check for) - i.e: `when: source_subdirs.matched is not defined or source_subdirs.matched == 0`

Answer (score 14):

You can avoid 'dict object' has no attribute by using jinja2 selectattr() syntax as in :

```
when: me|selectattr("cool", "defined")|list|length >0
```

idea obtained from Michael Hoglan at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ansible-project/8XJkHQgttLA

Answer (score 0):

Checking if the attribute is included in the set of attributes of the hash also works:

```
vars:
    key: "name_of_key"
...
when:
-   key not in hash_variable.keys()
```